# Using Camel to Parse CSV

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel

I am attempting to use Camel's bindy annotation to parse through a CSV. I have followed some tutorials online but cannnot seem to get them to work. I am new to this side of camel, so I dont quite understand the errors I am getting. For right now my CSV is very simple as I am just trying to understand how this functionallity works. 
The CSV currently looks likes this:

HDR|Suborg|CountryCode|BrokerFile|Batch|Time|Date|

The Error Im getting it this:

org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.ups.ttg.bsis.fromdos.AlamoHdr

Here is my code:

```
public class AlamoPipeRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    final DataFormat bindy  = new BindyCsvDataFormat(AlamoHdr.class);

    /*
     * Endpoints
     */ 
    @EnforceInitialization
    private Logging logging;

    @EnforceInitialization
    private RatingProfileAlamoSplitHandler ratingProfileAlamoSplitHandler;

    @EnforceInitialization
    private String start = "";

    @EnforceInitialization
    private String end = "";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Started Configure Method");

        /*
         * Basic Route
         */
        from(start)
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
        .routeId("processRatingProfile.alamo")
        //.beanRef("RatingProfileExchangeUtilies", "checkForNoRecords(*)")
        .beanRef("logging", "debug(*, 'Starting aggregation strategy loop...')")
        .split(body().tokenize("\n"), ratingProfileAlamoSplitHandler).streaming()
            .unmarshal(bindy)
            .setHeader("INDEX",    simple("${header.CamelSplitIndex}") )
            .setHeader("COMPLETE", simple("${header.CamelSplitComplete}") )
        .end()
        .beanRef("logging", "debug(*, 'Aggregation strategy loop complete...')")
        .removeHeader("lastRatingProfile")
        .to(end);
    }

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public void setEnd(String end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    public void setRatingProfileAlamoSplitHandler(RatingProfileAlamoSplitHandler ratingProfileAlamoSplitHandler) {
        this.ratingProfileAlamoSplitHandler = ratingProfileAlamoSplitHandler;
    }

    public void setLogging(Logging logging) {
        this.logging = logging;
    }
}



public class RatingProfileAlamoSplitHandler implements AggregationStrategy {    

    @EnforceInitialization
    private static Logging logging;

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        Integer currIndex = -1;
        boolean lastLine = false;

        if(newExchange != null) {
            currIndex = (Integer) newExchange.getIn().getHeader("INDEX");
            System.out.println("THIS IS THE INDEX: " + currIndex);

            /*lastLine = (Boolean) newExchange.getIn().getHeader("COMPLETE");
            System.out.println("THIS IS THE COMPLETE: " + lastLine);*/

            System.out.println("This IS THE BODY: " + newExchange.getIn().getBody());

            if(currIndex == 0) {
                AlamoHdr alamoHdr = (AlamoHdr) newExchange.getIn().getBody();
            }
        }

        return newExchange; 
    }

    public static void setLogging(Logging logging) {
        RatingProfileAlamoSplitHandler.logging = logging;
    }

}

public class AlamoHdr implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    @DataField(pos = 2, trim = true)
    private String suborg;

    @DataField(pos = 3, trim = true)
    private String countryCode;

    @DataField(pos = 4, trim = true)
    private String brokerFile;

    @DataField(pos = 5, trim = true)
    private String batch;

    @DataField(pos = 6, trim = true)
    private String time;

    @DataField(pos = 7, trim = true)
    private String date;

    public AlamoHdr(String suborg, String countryCode, String brokerFile, String batch, String time, String date) {
        super();
        this.suborg = suborg;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.brokerFile = brokerFile;
        this.batch = batch;
        this.time = time;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getSuborg() {
        return suborg;
    }

    public void setSuborg(String suborg) {
        this.suborg = suborg;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public String getBrokerFile() {
        return brokerFile;
    }

    public void setBrokerFile(String brokerFile) {
        this.brokerFile = brokerFile;
    }

    public String getBatch() {
        return batch;
    }

    public void setBatch(String batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AlamoHdr [suborg=" + suborg + ", countryCode=" + countryCode + ", brokerFile=" + brokerFile + ", batch="
                + batch + ", time=" + time + ", date=" + date + "]";
    }

    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: For some reason the error logs didnt print in my question... here they are

Comment: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.ups.ttg.bsis.fromdos.AlamoHdr

Comment: Please edit your question with your error logs, do not post logs in comments.

Comment: Check what endings your file has. I see that you expect \n but it can be differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may also come across this problem, I found what was going wrong. When using a | as your separator you need to pass it in like so

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\\|", skipFirstLine = false)
```

because the | is a meta character that represents the OR operation and we need a regular expression for this operation.

Also you cannot have a constructor in files like AlamoHdr because the variables are being populated through the binding not through calling the constructor.